# how to measure the CPU cycles of a C function in iPhone4 application with xCode4?

Tags: iphone, xcode4, cycle

The system time substraction may be one method, but it includes the running time for all the tasks/threads, the function is only in one thread of one task.
Instrument in Xcode may be another method, but how to measure the time for a specific function?

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand a few things here: firstly, the concept of a 'CPU cycle' isn't very useful. It's in fact fairly meaningless. You're never going to get an accurate result. You can use `valgrind` to get detailed output regarding the number of instructions being executed, and in **theory** (that's a big 'in theory') you could use this information to derive cycle counts. Realistically it's impossible, and not worth the effort.

One would have to ask **why** you'd want to find this out in the first place.

Comment: Thanks lxt, there is one algorithm with ARMV5TE assembly code, I can get it's CPU cycles using ARM RVDS debugger. Now I port the algorithm to iPhone, ARMv7, it works and give out the correct result. I need to know the performance of the algorithm in iPhon4, I can get the running time of the algorithms, like 201006 nano seconds, to compare with ARMV5TE, I need transfer it to cycles. if the iphone4 work frequency is 1GHz, I can say the algorithms use 201006 cycles in some degrees. if 667MHz, 134004 cycles is used. if 500MHz, 100503 cycles. so If I know the CPU frequency, it is done for the task.

Comment: Unfortunately, CPU frequency for A4 chips isn't published, and is known to vary between devices anyway. So I wouldn't necessarily make an assumption that the iPhone 4 runs at 1GHz all the time.

Comment: Is there any API function or system information to get the current frequency?